# Bash Loop with cut

Tags: bash

I have a file (called file) with a bunch of lines and a space between each like so:

```
abc 123
def 456
ghi 789
```

I need to loop through and grab each field to manipulate the text a bit. I've been trying to do it like this:

```
for i in `cat file`

do

var1=`echo ${i} | cut -d" " -f1`
var2=`echo ${i} | cut -d" " -f2`

echo "var1: ${var1} and var2: ${var2}"

done
```

Here's what I'm getting for output:

```
var1: abc and var2: abc
var1: 123 and var2: 123
var1: def and var2: def
var1: 456 and var2: 456
var1: ghi and var2: ghi
var1: 789 and var2: 789
```

For clarity, expected output would be:

```
var1: abc and var2: 123
var1: def and var2: 456
var1: ghi and var2: 789
```

Not sure why this isn't working. What can I do to get the expected output?

Comment: If my :manipulate", you mean "alter, then `cut` doesn't do that. You also don't need to `cat` to use `cut`. What is the expected output? Add it to your question?

Comment: I added the expected output. At this point I'm not attempting to manipulate any data, merely echo the expected variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/root/test.txt"

 while IFS=' ' read -r f1 f2
 do
     printf 'VAR1: %s VAR2: %s\n' "$f1" "$f2"
 done <"$input"
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome on serverfault. You might consider commenting your code. [Here](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) there is an intresting read for new contributors.

Comment: This works, but doesn't assign the values to variables.

Comment: It does, but the variables used in this example are called f1 and f2.

Answer (score 0):

@ddiser has what I imagine is a working solution, but doesn't explain why, which I believe is the question.

The answer is what "cat file" outputs - namely a list of strings separated by spaces and newlines.

When the for statement sees the result, it uses the whitespace character as a separator - is it is treating space as you expect it to treat the newline character.  To prove this you could modify the file to use a character other then space (eg a comma or pipe), then change the delimeter on the cut commands and this will work.  You could even use the same file format if instead of "cat file" you used cat file|tr ' ' '|' " (which is not to say this is an appropriate use of cat, but it should work)

Comment: This actually seems to work, not sure why the whitespace is treated as a newline?

Comment: @dstana Its not! Its that space and newlines are both treated as delimiters.  Another solution to your problem would be to add a line  IFS="\n" above your for loop to surpress this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to combine the input from the previous contributors and also use your format some.  Also, I have modernized your code which you should also consider more broadly in your coding.  Let me know if you have any questions.

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do 
    var1="$( printf '%b' "${line}" | cut -d " " -f1 )" 
    var2="$( printf '%b' "${line}" | cut -d " " -f2 )" 
    printf '%s\n' "var1:  ${var1} and var2:  ${var2}" 
done < /path/to/your/file.txt
```

This will work because read sends each line of the file to the loop.  Your version doesn't because cat sends the file to the loop without dividing it first.

Regardless, as you can probably guess, there are many other ways to accomplish the same thing, and so you really can choose from many different tools within bash to make your solution.